# mod_pagespeed not minify my JS Files

Tags: nginx, webserver, mod-pagespeed

I have install Nginx with mod_pagespeed, however, the js file is not getting minifieid. I have give 777 permission to  /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed already. I can access the file fine thru http://localhost:8888/js/my.js

```
server {
       listen 8888;


        # Pagespeed main settings                                                                                                                
        pagespeed on;
        pagespeed FileCachePath  /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/;


        location / {
                 root /var/www/static;
                 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that PageSpeed is active? The responses should include an `X-PageSpeed` header?

You should testing through an HTML page, not directly by accessing the JS file.

JS minification is one of the core filters enabled by default, so it should work without further configuratin.